# Function that returns function can't be imported NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have the function `query` in api.ts and it works perfectly fine in this file.

```
export const query = <C extends ControllerConfig>(
  path: string
): ((args?: C['args']) => Promise<C['payload']>) => {
  return async (args?: C['args']): Promise<C['payload']> => {
    const { body, ...rest } = args;
    if (body) throw new Error('Body not processed in query operation');
    path = pathFromArgs(path, rest);
    const { data } = await client.get<C['payload']>(path);
    return data;
  };
};
```

When I try to import it into another file it says it's not a function.

club.api.ts:

```
const getClubs = query<GetClubs>('/clubs/');
```

Here is the error:
`TypeError: (0 , ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.query) is not a function`

If I move the function declaration into club.api.ts then call the function it works fine. Is this an issue with NextJS or the Webpack configuration?

Comment: I don't think Next.js bundles things from your API files into your frontend files.

Comment: those are just suffixes they are not in the `/api` directory

Comment: You need to please give us some more details here. Nextjs has a concept of [api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction). Is this a server-side or client-side function? How are you importing it? Etc etc.

Comment: @JaredSmith `api.ts` and `club.api.ts` are in `src/lib/api`, I'm using a directory export from `/api` (index.ts) then importing the `query` function into `club.api.ts` with `import { query } from '.';`. This is all client side.

Comment: Show the code please. Edit into the question. Also please don't name any of your directories `/api` in Nextjs, it *already* has an `/api` directory that gets special treatment. I realize that this is in `/src/lib` but an experienced dev is going to hear "api" in a next context and immediately think "server route".

Comment: Discovered the issue had to do with the path aliases. When I switched to relative paths it was alright.